# Get the mean curve of a set of curves with different amount of points

Tags: c#, math, 3d, mean, curve

So I have a set of curves, all of them have different amount of values, they always start in X=0 but end in different X=N.

Example:

*** Curve 1

X = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Y = -1, 1, 2, -1, 2, 3

*** Curve 2

X = 0, 1, 2, 3

Y = -0.5, 1.2, 2.5, -3

*** Curve 3

X = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

Y = -1.1, 2, 1, 0, 1.3, 4, 2

Now, I want to get a curve (or a set of points that represent a mean curve), but I am having trouble on how to compute this.

My first approach was to use the maximum value of each X as 1 (N=1), and then adapt all the values between 0 and 1 so to have a similar scale for every curve. But I still have different amount of values, so I cant figure out how to do an average of them at this point.

I have to do this in C#, so I cant be using matlab or similar. And eventually move from 1D to do the same in a 3D trajectory.

Can someone point me in the right direction or a methodology to look at?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this needs to be informed by what your end goal is - what does it mean to take the mean of two paths (reluctant to say curve when they are discrete) that are of differing lengths?

Comment: Given some input X find two nearest points in curve C[0], use linear interpolation to find value Y[0]. Repeat for all *m* curves: Y_mean = (Y[0] + ... + Y[m-1])/m. This will allow to draw your mean line for any X which are lower than minimal C[].X. For example specify X > 100, your data will not give meaningfull result for this.

Comment: I think the keywords you should google for are 'interpolation' and 'curve fitting'. You need to decide how you take these discrete values and get approximate mathematical representations _f1(x), f2(x), f3(x)_ of each curve. Then the average curve would be the average of all these: _f'(x) = (f1(x) + f2(x) + f3(x)) / 3_

Comment: So @eocron, I see that interpolation is a thing here. The key action is to find a reasonable way to make all curves of the "same size".

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Basically, same as the adobe comment.